# Sabre get hotels in specific city API

Tags: postman, sabre

i want to get the available hotels in a specific city ex (Cairo) using postman requests

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the OTA_HotelAvailRQ. Before that you need to open a session. My basic postman request for the Hotelavailbility is here: https://www.getpostman.com/collections/b42e8f3eb34f5d2a6ea8 - already set to CAI